# Proving that if $f_n \rightarrow f$ uniformly and $f_n$ is integrable then $\int_a^b f_n d\alpha\rightarrow \int_a^b fd\alpha$

Tags: real-analysis

This is theorem 7.16 in Rudin's Principles of Mathematical Analysis 6/E.

This is probably very obvious, but I am having problems with the very first step. Rudin writes,

> It suffices to prove this for real $f_n$. Put $\epsilon_n=\sup|f_n(x)-f(x)|$ with the supremum being taken over $a\leq x\leq b$. Then,$$f_n-\epsilon_n\leq f\leq f_n+\epsilon_n$$

I am having troubles seeing this. I can see that we have

$$\begin{align} 
|f(x)| &= |f(x)-f_n(x)+f_n(x)| \\
&\leq|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)| \\
&\leq\sup|f(x)-f_n(x)|+|f_n(x)| \\
&=\epsilon_n+|f_n(x)|
\end{align}$$

which seems very close to what I need but I can't see if this implies the above equality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$|f-f_n|<\epsilon_n\Rightarrow-\epsilon_n<f-f_n<\epsilon_n\Rightarrow f_n-\epsilon_n<f<f_n+\epsilon_n$.

Comment: almost want to delete this question in shame.

Comment: @crf, it is alright. Easy questions sometimes are hard to me also.